# How to add generic type to one of the object's property which Iam getting from Objet destructuring?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

This is my line of code:

```
       const { userName }: { userName: string } = useSelector((s: ReduxType) => s.currentUser.info) || '';
```

Iam getting this warning " Property 'userName' is missing in type '{}' but required in type '{ userName: string; }"

info is an object which contains following properties

```
  type userInfo = {
                id: number;
                userName: string;
                userEmail: string;
                created_date: string;
                last_updated: string;
                last_login: string;
                active: boolean;
                fullName: string;
                };
```

If I use

```
 const { userName }: any = useSelector((s: ReduxType) => s.currentUser.info) || '';
```

then warning will disappear but i want to use proper generic type

Thank you in adavnce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to make userName as optional-type

```js
const { userName }: { userName?: string } = useSelector((s: ReduxType) => s.currentUser.info) || '';
```

Answer (score 1):

use `Partial`

```
const { userName }: Partial<{ userName: string }> = ...
```

Comment: This one also works